# how can i show up powershell running screen in task scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want powershell script running after reboot.
So I set task scheduler like below.
Powershell is running. But I powershell console screen not show up after reboot.
how can i show up powershell running screen in task scheduler?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system account won't be able to create a UI in a user session. You'll want to run as a user.